# Размер памяти занимаемый форком

Tags: php, память

Столкнулся со странным поведением при форке через `pcntl_fork`

Возьмем простой скрипт вечно живущего демона

```php
pcntl_fork();
while (true) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

И сравним потребление памяти у родителя и ребенка
[image: memory-usage]

Видно, что дочерний процесс занимет примерно на треть меньше операвтивной памяти.
Если копнуть немного глубже и сравнить вывод `pmap -x 1172 1173` для обоих процессов увидим, такую картину
[image: memory-allocated-diff]

Если я правильно понимаю, то при старте php аллоцирует памяти с запасом на себя, а так же на все свои модули и этот запас довольно ощутимый, особенно если у вас на одном инстансе запускается множество демонов.

Получается таким хитрым способом можно урезать потребление памяти вашим демоном

```php
if (pcntl_fork() > 0) {
    die();
}
while (true) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

В чем подвох, только в том, что придется тратить время на аллокацию памяти при необходимости?

Comment: При форке процесса используется copy-on-write страниц памяти между родителем и ребенком. Возможно сейчас ситуация улучшилась. Но когда я разбирался с вопросом, ни одна утилита не могла внятно показать сколько реальной физической памяти кем использовано. Были какие-то наброски уровня ядра, но на amd64 они уже не работали.

Comment: При тестировании я смог запустить тысячу форков демона в докер контейнере, в таких же условиях я не смог сделать даже 600 запусков в обычном режиме и влез  в swap. Думаю памяти используется все же меньше.

Comment: Т. е. в обычном, это 600 раз `php ...`, a с форком один раз `php ...` и внутри 1000 раз форк?

Comment: Или обычный это 1-й листинг, а в оптимальном 2-й?

Comment: Да, 600 раз ‘php test.php’. Во втором это цикл с форком  одного и того же процесса. В принципе зависимость видно, и при меньших объёмах, просто хотелось выжать максимум.

Comment: Выходит так: В первом случае php инициализируется 600 раз, каждый раз забирая себе памяти. Во втором случае php инициализируется 1 раз, а все форки разделяют (совместно используют) с родителем эту память. Но тут надо учесть, что как только ребенок начнет активно действовать и писать в какие-то переменные, страницы памяти снова будут становиться раздельными. Так можно заметно сэкономить память и процессор на инициализации. Но в какой мере -- предсказать невозможно, толко написать реальный код, запустить и сравнить.

Comment: В перле, например, даже просто при чтении переменной у нее может измениться рефкаунт или закешироватся представление. А страница памяти достаточно крупная. В php -- не знаю

Comment: Для выжимания максимума можно и язык поменять. Тут зависит от задачи io-bound/cpu-bound. И от предрасположенности к разным языкам.

Comment: У нас вся команда на php пишет, ничего сверх нагружённого  в этих местах, но  демонов очень много. Инстансы приходится очень большие брать и если есть возможность с ничего поиметь  память почему нет. Для io/cpu bound Go

Comment: Да, я как раз о Go подумал. У него порог вхождения сравним с php, а эффективность выше. Я сам на scala остановился, но это не для любой команды. Котлин еще симпотично смотрится.

Comment: Если есть кому админить, то иногда дешевле железо взять. Сервер Б/У, 40 потоков, 200Г памяти -- <1000$ вроде бывает

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(обобщая комментарии выше)

При форке процесса используется copy-on-write страниц памяти между родителем и ребенком.
Если php инициализируется 1 раз, а потом форкается, все форки разделяют (совместно используют) с родителем эту память.
На этом можно экономить память и время на инициализацию (если она тюжелая).

Но тут надо учесть, что как только процесс-ребенок начнет активно работать с памятью, страницы памяти снова будут становиться раздельными.
В какой мере память станет раздельной -- предсказать невозможно, только написать реальный код, запустить и сравнить.

/* О средсвах, позволяющих подробно узнать, какие страницы физической памяти используется совместно какими процессами из-за copy-on-write, мне не известно. */

---

Нашел достаточно простой способ:

`pmap -X` содержит столбик `Pss` -- "proportional set size" --
Объем страниц в памяти поделенный на количество процессов разделячщих страницы.
Так если у процесса 1000 страниц, которые пользует лично он, и еще 1000 страниц, общих с другим процессом, то `Pss` будет 1500.
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt

Запускаем скрипт, который инициализирует на куче большой массив, делает форк, и постепенно меняет случайные значения в массиве:

```
perl -e '$max=1000000; @c=1..$max; $pid=fork; @c[map{rand()*$max}1..100]=() while sleep 1'
```

Находим пару процессов скрипта и наблюдаем `pmap -X`:

```
perl -e 'while(sleep 1){$pids=join" ",map{/([0-9]+)/ && $1!=$$?"$1":()}`ps -ef|grep perl|grep sleep`; print `pmap -X $pids`}'
```

Видно, что `Pss` на строке `heap` стартует с половины `Rss` и постепенно увеличивается с убывающей скоростью.

Еще пишут, что `/proc/<pid>/pagemap` содержит соответствие между виртуальной и физической памятью (в бинарном виде), и имея CAP_SYS_ADMIN, можно его читать:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt
Но с этим я эксперементировать уже не стал.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10859869/9435985 ?

Comment: @Total Pusher, да надо будет глянуть